How do I write to a Vertica database using Polars' write_database() in Python?
I'm trying to write to a Vertica database using Polars' write_database().
vertica-python and SQLAlchemy are installed.
import polars as pl
import sqlalchemy as sa

df = pl.DataFrame({"str_col": ["a", "b", "c"]})
df.write_database(table_name="schema.table", connection="vertica+vertica_python://user:pw@host:port/dbname", if_exists="replace")

When I run this code, QueryError and ProgrammingError occur as shown below.
`QueryError: Severity: ERROR, Message: Type "TEXT" does not exist, Sqlstate: 42704, Routine: typenameTypeId, File: parse_type.c, Line: 236, Error Code: 5108, SQL: ' CREATE TABLE "schema"."table" ( \t"str_col" TEXT ) '`

`ProgrammingError: (vertica_python.errors.QueryError) Severity: ERROR, Message: Type "TEXT" does not exist, Sqlstate: 42704, Routine: typenameTypeId, File: parse_type.c, Line: 236, Error Code: 5108, SQL: ' CREATE TABLE "schema"."table" ( \t"str_col" TEXT ) '`

The cause seems to be that str_col is specified as "TEXT" instead of "VARCHAR" in SQL.
How do I resolve this issue ?
df = pl.DataFrame({"int_col": [1, 2, 3]})

If it is an int type column, it can be written without any error.
An error occurs with str type columns.
The version of each module is listed below.

polars         0.20.22
vertica-python 1.3.8
SQLAlchemy     1.4.16

